# Enable touchscreen on Lenovo Yoga 11s Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, touchscreen

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo Yoga 11s (Ivybridge).

when I first ran the installation, the touchpad didn't work but the touchscreen did.

I foolishly tried to install to an SD Card only to discover I couldn't boot from it. The second time I ran the installation process the touchpad DID work! But I didn't realize TouchScreen wasn't working until after installing. I used the whole disk on the installation and I've installed the latest updates.

How can I enable the touchscreen? I'm pretty sure its supported cause I already used it the first time and apparently I'm the only one without it working.

Comment: touchscreen or touchpad? this is confusing

Answer (score 2):

On my Lenovo yoga 11s I went into **Software & Updates** and allowed proprietary drivers, and then did a full update (and upgrade), rebooted and then my touchscreen worked, not as smooth as on windows 8 but usable.

Answer (score 2):

Run in terminal:

```
sudo rmmod psmouse && sudo modprobe psmouse
```

You can run it at startup by pasting the above code in this file (by doing this you will not have to run it in terminal every time you turn on your computer):

```
/etc/rc.local
```

In Yoga 11s and other Lenovo models, I think we need to wait for a new kernel update to solve the problem definitely.